# Database Architecture regarding User Accounts and Account Deletion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm designing a database that will be the backend for a marketplace website. There will be buyers and sellers creating accounts. I am planning on having a single sign in form for all types of account and a central accounts table that will hold account details common to all types of account, where user credentials will be stored and can be checked against when any user signs in.

The user credentials will consist of Email and Password. The Email column of the table will be a unique column so an email address can only corrospond to a single account.

But the problem appears when a user wants to delete their account. A user will be able to terminate their account but much of the data related to their account shall be retained in the database. It shall be necessary to retain the data as it will be relevant to other users and the site in general. For example messages, orders, disputes etc. As data has to be kept for buyers to see details about sellers in their past order, really all account data has to be kept and just given a status of terminated.

So what happens if once a user has terminated their account but they try to create a new account with the same email address? They wouldn't be allowed to because there is already an account with that email address and a terminated status.

My first idea was to replace the email address with a null when an account is terminated. So the email could be used again for a new account, but then I realised a unique column can only have one NULL value.

My next idea was to transfer termiated accounts to another table and remove the email column. However this doesn't make sense as many other tables in the database will have foreign keys that reference the original table.

Another Idea is to have three core account tables.

AccountInventory: AccountID_PK, Status

ActiveAccounts: AccountID_PK, Email, Password, PasswordSalt, AccType, AccStatus

TerminatedAccounts: AccountID_PK, AccType

This way I could reference the AccountInventory table with foreign keys in my other tables. Use the ActiveAccounts table to check credentials as users sign in. And move deleted accounts to the TerminatedAccounts table whilst still maintaining referential integrity of other data to that account as foreign keys reference AccountInventory.

Is this the best way to achive this functionality of enabling users to reuse an email address whilst maintaing the integrity of the data? It seems a little awkward to me having an AccountInventory table that essentially holds nothing other than Account IDs that all other tables that need to JOIN with ActiveAccounts or Terminated Accounts will have to JOIN though.

So is this the best solution or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Kind Regards,
Duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a User table with an unique key based on email AND status?

You still can have referential integrity but poses a problem when that user wants to cancel second account. In this case, you could to merge those two accounts, as refers to same user.

If that merge isn't possible, you could also to create a date range where that account is valid and making it part of your unique index, and enforce there's only an email address valid at time using triggers or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rubens, If the user did cancel and rejoin twice that would be a problem. Also I know it is highly unlikely/rare but what if a user terminated their account, then someone else took possession of their email and this new person then joined the site. Then merging accounts would mean merging two different people.

Comment: So, probably using that date range could be a better option. Store user email, status and a date range, starting on creation date and ending at 9999-12-31 to could use that information on login process. When a user cancels its account, set end date to current date and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yes thanks for this idea. This could definately work, and only Email and close date would be needed for the unique key actually and I don't think a triggar would be needed either. And actually the close date column could be allowed to accept NULLs, which would be slightly nicer than a future date. This is possibly a better solution than mine. Maybe they are both valid solutions? It would be good to hear a few more opinions about this.

Comment: The only slight problem with the date solution though is that all terminated accounts will be in the same table as live accounts meaning as the database scales and gets old and fills up with terminated accounts there could be a performance hit on reads as users sign in.

Comment: I'm not sure if a performance hit could to be a problem, as you generally provide a user key or a date range when you ask for reports. I think that can be managed with an appropriate index set.

Comment: The Primary Key index on the Accounts table would be an ever increasing integer which will be the AccountID. Plus an index on the Email/DateTerminated columns for when a user signs in.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you should change the way you think about user accounts.

In your system, users aren't really allowed to delete their accounts. When you're thinking about this problem, stop using the word *delete*; it clouds your thinking.

Users *are* allowed to start and stop their relationship with you many times. So their account can have many periods of "active" and "inactive" status, each with a start and end date. (You might have better words than "active" and "inactive".)

It depends on your app, but I don't think anything except their account status has to be recognized as "active" or "inactive". In other words, I don't think historical messages, orders, and disputes need to know anything about the account's current status.

**One more important thing to think about**

Let's say I have my own domain--wibble.com--and I have an email account named mary@wibble.com. I let my domain lapse. Someone else, also named Mary, registers it. What should happen when the new mary@wibble.com tries to create an account on your site?

If that sounds far-fetched, a local university assigns email addresses to every student during registration. The university terminates those accounts 6 months after you graduate. Usernames are based on the letters in your real name.  Terminated email addresses are reusable immediately after termination. Same email address; different person. What should happen?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Catcall. I appreciate delete is a confusing word. I was looking at user accounts from the user perspective, to them it is delete. But you're right I'll call it terminated probably. However I'm not sure you quite saw the issue. Accounts are not just active or inactive. If a user terminates their account they have 28 days to cancel the termination otherwise that account is closed for good. Now this stops the situation of new person but same email getting a past account. But there is problem that a new account/same email can't be created because of the unique key on email

Comment: So we have two solutions so far - 1 - Split Accounts table into three tables: AccountsInventory(list of all accounts ever), ActiveAccounts, and TerminatedAccounts. Data references AccountsInventory so that referential integrity is not broken when an account is transfered from ActiveAccounts to TerminatedAccounts. Cons: JOINS have to happen through AccountsInventory. Solution 2 - Create the unique key on Email and DateTermianted(nullable) columns. Cons: May not scale well, could be a performance hit.